# MongoDB average aggregation doesn't work properly

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I'm newbie to NoSQL databases. What I want is to show the `title`, `url` and the `avg(ratings)`.
The sample data looks like the following:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52b3833bd3e98582d2bfb628"),
    "author" : {
        "name" : "Graydon Hoare",
        "email" : "graydon@gmail.com"
    },
    "title" : "Why Rust ditched pure functions",
    "body" : "sth",
    "url" : "http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.rust.devel/3674/focus=3855",
    "date" : ISODate("2013-04-30T13:23:00.000Z"),
    "starred" : 105,
    "ratings" : [ 
        3, 
        5, 
        3, 
        2, 
        4, 
        1, 
        3, 
        3, 
        3, 
        2, 
        3
    ],
    "comments" : [ 
        {
            "user" : "tr0lltherapy",
            "upVotes" : 18,
            "downVotes" : 2,
            "text" : "something",
            "replies" : [ 
                {
                    "user" : "thedeemon",
                    "upVotes" : 10,
                    "downVotes" : 0,
                    "text" : "something"
                }, 
                {
                    "user" : "mcandre",
                    "upVotes" : 0,
                    "downVotes" : 5,
                    "text" : "Performance? There are already a slew of performant languages. Assembler, C, C++, Go. What does Rust actually offer that's new and useful in this category, other than using my favorite abbreviation for the named function keyword, fn?"
                }, 
                {
                    "user" : "lacosaes0",
                    "upVotes" : 30,
                    "downVotes" : 6,
                    "text" : "Particular emphasis on memory safety."
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "user" : "hypster",
            "upVotes" : 30,
            "downVotes" : 2,
            "text" : "tl;dr everybody was type-fu fighting",
            "replies" : [ 
                {
                    "user" : "homoiconic",
                    "upVotes" : 15,
                    "downVotes" : 0,
                    "text" : "Here comes the Big Boss, Hu! Simon Peyton-Jones."
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "tags" : [ 
        "Rust", 
        "Computer", 
        "Programming"
    ],
    "draft" : true,
    "published" : true
}
```

I have tried the following query, but it doesn't work properly and puts `null` value in the average. I don't know how should I fix it.

```
db.getCollection('links').aggregate(
    [
        {
            $match: {
                "author.email": /@gmail.com$/
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                _id: 0,
                title: 1,
                url: 1,
                avgRatings: {
                    $avg: "$Ratings"
                }
            }
        }
    ])
```

Expected output is:

```
title: "Why Rust ditched pure functions", url: "http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.rust.devel/3674/focus=3855", 
avgRatings: 2.90
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo, `$Ratings`; use `$ratings` as below.  Aggregation syntax is case sensitive.

```
db.getCollection('links').aggregate(
    [
        {
            $match: {
                "author.email": /@gmail.com$/
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                _id: 0,
                title: 1,
                url: 1,
                avgRatings: {
                    $avg: "$ratings"
                }
            }
        }
    ])
```

Comment: what does `project` actually do? what is the difference of `group` and `project`?

Comment: $project passes along the documents with the requested fields to the next stage in the pipeline.  $group groups documents by some specified expression and outputs to the next stage a document for each distinct grouping.